# How do I get combo boxes to become invisible when the selection is no longer selected in a multiselect list box?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, listbox, multi-select

I have a multiselect list box (nameDatabase) that when I select an option, a combo box will appear, and I can use it. However, when I unselect it, the combo box stays visible after it is unselected.

This is what I currently have to make them visible and place the items selected to a text box:

```
Private Sub nameDatabase_AfterUpdate()

Dim strEng As String
Dim varItem As Variant
    
For Each varItem In Me.nameDatabase.ItemsSelected
    
    strEng = strEng & ", " & Me.nameDatabase.ItemData(varItem)
        
Next
    
If Len(strEng) > 0 Then
    
    strEng = Mid(strEng, 2)
        
End If
    
Me.TestBox = strEng

If nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "A" Then
        
    codeJBox.Visible = True
        
ElseIf nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "B" Then
    
    codeSBox.Visible = True

ElseIf nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C" Then

    codePBox.Visible = True
    codeABox.Visible = True
   
End If

End Sub
```

I have tried to have a text box have the selections in it and if, for example, "A" is not in there it will go away though it didn't work, or I did something wrong. I have a feeling it is something simple I'm missing to make the combo box disappear and that I'm overthinking everything.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to help you with a solution without seeing more of your code, rather than just the snippet you have included ... suggest including the entire Sub/Function (or a larger part of it if it is very long and includes non-relevant code)

Comment: I included the rest of the code in the AfterUpdate. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the variable `Value` come from? It's not defined in the function.

Comment: Value is whatever is selected in the list box. So if A is selected then combo box appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your use-case (it didn't, see edit):

```
Private Sub nameDatabase_Change()
    Dim Value As Long
    'Value = 1 'was for testing
    If nameDatabase.Text <> "" Then
        codeJBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "A"
        codeSBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "B"
        codePBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C"
        codeABox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C"
    Else
        codeJBox.Visible = False
        codeSBox.Visible = False
        codePBox.Visible = False
        codeABox.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It turns the 4 invisible if nothing is selected and when something is typed only makes the ones you need visible. Let me know if something is unclear.

**EDIT:**
It appears I mistook your question for a normal listbox/combobox, not one from access. As such I can't test this further but you can try the following code which should still work. Let me know if it doesn't.

```
Private Sub nameDatabase_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strEng As String
    Dim varItem As Variant
        
    For Each varItem In Me.nameDatabase.ItemsSelected
        If Len(strEng) = 0 Then
            strEng = Me.nameDatabase.ItemData(varItem)
        Else
            strEng = strEng & ", " & Me.nameDatabase.ItemData(varItem)
        End If
    Next varItem
        
    Me.TestBox = strEng
    
    codeJBox.Visible = InStr(strEng, "A") > 0
    codeSBox.Visible = InStr(strEng, "B") > 0
    codePBox.Visible = InStr(strEng, "C") > 0
    codeABox.Visible = InStr(strEng, "C") > 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you're doing but nameDatabase is the list box. I should edit the post to specify that. The ".text" doesn't come up for it.

Comment: See my edit for another attempt, my apologies for the confusion. I don't think you need the mysterious `Value` variable you had going on either if you're already making a string of all the selected values.

Comment: That works perfectly. Didn't realize I didn't need the Value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could initially hide them all:

```vb
codeJBox.Visible = False
codeSBox.Visible = False
codePBox.Visible = False
codeABox.Visible = False

If nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "A" Then
        
    codeJBox.Visible = True
        
ElseIf nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "B" Then
    
    codeSBox.Visible = True

ElseIf nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C" Then

    codePBox.Visible = True
    codeABox.Visible = True
   
End If
```

Comment: Now it just makes the last selection disappear when multiples are selected and not when its respective list box selection is unselected.

Answer (score 0):

It's still difficult to tell whether the following will do what you want without seeing the wider context the Sub is in, especially for `Value`, however, you could try this which doesn't just make the ComboBoxes visible if the selection is appropriate, but also hides them if the selection is not appropriate

```
Private Sub nameDatabase_AfterUpdate()

Dim strEng As String
Dim varItem As Variant
    
For Each varItem In Me.nameDatabase.ItemsSelected
    
    strEng = strEng & ", " & Me.nameDatabase.ItemData(varItem)
        
Next
    
If Len(strEng) > 0 Then
    
    strEng = Mid(strEng, 2)
        
End If
    
Me.TestBox = strEng

codeJBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "A"
codeSBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "B"
codePBox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C"
codeABox.Visible = nameDatabase.Column(Value) = "C"

End Sub
```

... I have to mention that I have not been able to test this code without having the wider code-base to work it within.

Comment: What do you mean by wider code-base? The list box and combo boxes are the only objects on the form. I can't provide anymore because there isn't any.